# ImageFolder dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

Do `ImageFolder` datasets have labels? What details are stored in an `ImageFolder` dataset?

I got this error when i tried to get the label of an `ImageFolder`dataset

```
AttributeError: 'Subset' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) is designed for classification tasks, it is your directory structure that dictates the label each image is assigned.

The example given on documentation page is the following:

```
root/dog/xxx.png
root/dog/xxy.png
root/dog/[...]/xxz.png

root/cat/123.png
root/cat/nsdf3.png
root/cat/[...]/asd932_.png
```

Images `dog/xxx.png`, `dog/xxy.png`, and all other images under `/dog` will be assigned label `0` (which corresponding here to the `"dog"` class).

Similarly `cat/123.png`, `cat/nsdf3.png`, and all other images under `/cat` will be assigned a different label, here `1`.

Comment: thank you for the brief clarification.
Is there any way to retrieve that 0,1 values.

Comment: if you initialize your dataset and iterate over it, it will produce `(image tensor, label integer)` *tuple* pair.